# How to Remove Extra carriage return In Notepad from Microsoft Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to remove extra comma and carriage return at the of the text.
This code only remove extra comma :

```
Sub test()
Dim fn As String, txt As String
fn = Application.GetOpenFilename("TextFiles,*.txt")
If fn = "" Then Exit Sub
txt = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fn).ReadAll
 With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True: .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = ",+$"
    Open Replace(fn, ".txt", "_Clean.txt") For Output As #1
        Print #1, .Replace(txt, "")
    Close #1
 End With
End Sub
```

How to remove extra break line/ carriage return at the of the text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to remove the CR/LF at the **end** of the file, just add a `;` to the end of your `Print` statement, i.e.

```
Print #1, .Replace(txt, "");
```